# Microsoft Bitlocker Decryption interrupted. Cannot decrypt again

Tags: decryption, bitlocker

I've locked on of my USB drive with BitLocker. When I was decrypting(removing BitLocker), my PC went off due to power cut in the halfway of decryption. Now, when I'm trying again to decrypt using password as well as decryption key, it says password invalid or key not valid.

How could I decrypt it? Or did I lost my USB? It has important data as well.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: USB drives are prone to errors even on hardware level i.e. gets damaged or lost easily. They should only be used for transferring files, not as a storage. Bitlocker on a USB drive protects the data from leaking especially when the USB drive gets lost.

Comment: It should be noted that "important data" should **always be duplicate**. If you have your important data in one point, then you have a single point of failure. In your case, that point has failed, and your data is most likely lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have recovery key for the bitlocker volume, try using that. It is possible the header was damaged. If you don't, there is no simple way to recover the data and it is likely gone.

Comment: I've already tried using recovery key but cannot decrypt now.